# What happens when you copy a pointer obtained from new, and then delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

This is a problem based on C++11.

What‘s happened when I delete a dynamic array by another pointer? Has this dynamic array been deleted actually?

```
    int* a = new int[NUM01];
    int* a1 = a;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM01; i++) {
        a1[i] = 0;
    }

    delete[] a1;    //What's happened?
```

I try to observe `a[0]`.

```
    cout << a[0] << endl;

    delete[] a1;

    cout << a[0] << endl;
```

The result is：
0
-572662307

What's the real?

Comment: undefined Behaviour. you access a  deleted memory location

Comment: same as `delete[] a`. You deallocate memory pointed by a pointer. Both `a` and `a1` point to the same memory block, because they are equal.

Comment: Deletion happens to pointers, not variables. It doesn't matter which variable is holding the pointer.

Comment: Using a pointer which points at deleted memory is **not** a good way to test if memory has been deleted. All you invoke is *undefined behaviour* which by definition is impossible to test for.

Comment: If you use `g++` or `clang++`, add the compiler options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` - It will tell you about the invalid memory access after `delete[]` when you run the program.

Comment: This is one of the reasons you should not use raw pointers and new/delete in C++ anymore even though a lot of legacy material still teaches that. In current C++ you should use std::make_unique/std::unique_ptr, std::vector (for resizable arrays) or std::make_shared/std::shared_ptr.  In your case the best option would have been `std::vector<int>`